# How to compare multiple rows in same table?

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have one table likes:

```
ID    Name     Amount     Date         
1      A        50      03/04/2018 
2      A        40      03/04/2018 
3      A        30      03/04/2018 
4      A        20      03/04/2018
5      A        10      08/04/2018
6      B        20      08/04/2018
7      B        15      08/04/2018
8      B        10      08/04/2018
9      A        100     08/07/2018
10     A        90      08/07/2018
11     A        80      08/07/2018
12     A        70      08/07/2018
```

I want to find the changes of the Amount at A in the table, For example, A's amount just goes down at 08/04/2018, but get new amount at 08/07/2018. I want to find these two rows for analysis( min value at old amount and max value at new amount):

```
5      A        10      08/04/2018
9      A        100     08/07/2018
```

I want both rows before and after an exclusively positive change.

Is that possible?

My code is:

```
SELECT cur.name, cur.amount
FROM tableA pre INNER JOIN tableA cur ON cur.id = pre.id + 1
WHERE cur.name = pre.name
ORDER BY cur.ID, cur.amount.
```

Comment: You didn't specify rules that lead from input to output.

Comment: Why do you INNER JOIN `cur.id = pre.id + 1`?

Comment: @Socrates I think my logic is chaos~ i saw it was sequence, so i just added 1

Comment: @how could i get my ideal result? thanks in advance

Comment: @Crazymango Still not quite sure how exactly you want to achieve your goal. Please edit your post and be more specific. Remember that we don't know your context.

Comment: @Socrates actually, i want to get changes of amount in A.  I want to get these two rows for analysis.

Comment: @Crazymango So you want to have all the A's and not just one? You want to have the amount difference from every older A to the newer A?

Comment: @Socrates I just want to pick out these two rows and then i will store them into my specific table for analysis. I have thousands of records like this. I just gave you a specific example.

Comment: @ you don't need to worry about other A. In this case I try to compare the rows that contained by A. And then find out smallest A at a date and find biggest A at another date.

Comment: Why do you have one of the JOIN conditions in the WHERE clause?

Comment: @jarlh It's not a join, it's a filter for A and B names.

Comment: @Socrates, still it's a join condition, names or not doesn't matter.

Comment: @jarlh Actually, you're not that wrong. ;) Still, same result.

Answer (score 2):

You need to work with two views on the same table, which is what you did with `pre` and `cur`. What you didn't do though is limit your output to A fields, hence put that in the `WHERE` clause. You then have to calculate the amount difference between the `pre` view and the `cur` view by creating a new field.

Check out this query showing you every field you use here. You'll have to adapt it to your needs.

```
SELECT pre.ID AS pre_id, pre.name AS pre_name, pre.amount AS pre_amount, cur.ID AS cur_id, cur.name AS cur_name, cur.amount AS cur_amount, cur.amount - pre.amount AS pre_cur_amount_diff 
FROM tableA pre INNER JOIN tableA cur ON pre.ID + 1 = cur.ID 
WHERE pre.name = cur.name;
```

**EDIT 1:**

You may be looking at this:

```
SELECT cur.ID, cur.name, cur.amount - pre.amount as Amount 
FROM tableA pre INNER JOIN tableA cur ON pre.ID + 1 = cur.ID 
WHERE pre.name = cur.name
ORDER BY cur.ID, Amount;
```

Comment: sorry, i could not get ideal result.

Comment: when I run this script. the result looks like it print out every thing. But I just want two rows: 5      A        10      08/04/2018
                               9      A        100     08/07/2018

Comment: @Socates, it looks like we could not get this result?

Comment: @Crazymango It sounds to me that the main problem is your lack of knowledge in SQL. You may want to get yourself a book as you'll run into many other problems in your future. The above query outputs every mentioned field so that you know what values you are comparing. You have to just remove those you don't want to show.

Comment: @Socates, I am learner~ maybe  right now i am lack of logic on SQL. so painful

Comment: @Socates, I tried this code based on yours:  SELECT pre.ID AS pre_id, pre.name AS pre_name, pre.amount AS pre_amount, cur.ID AS cur_id, cur.name AS cur_name, cur.amount AS cur_amount
FROM tableA pre INNER JOIN tableA cur 
On pre.name = cur.name WHERE cur.date<>pre.date order cur.id

Comment: @Socates, could i say no? :(

Comment: @Crazymango Not really. Describe how what you want differs from what I suggested in the answer.

Comment: @Socates, you could see that in the table i have 9 rows that is related with A. Right now, i don't want their differs. The code above will return couples of rows for A. but my ideal result should just return two rows.

Comment: @Crazymango Ok I understand. Explain why ID 5 and ID 9 and not the others.

Comment: @Socates, right now i just cut a small piece of the data as a example. Normally, in my case,  A's amount will not be increased in the future. However, A 's amount is increased at 08/07/2018. That is the thing i need to pick out.

Comment: @Crazymango So you want both rows before and after an exclusively positive change?

Comment: @Socates. Bingo! That is what i want.

Comment: @Crazymango What programming language do you use for MySQL database access?

Comment: @Crazymango I think you'll have to handle this case using your favourite programming language. The problem is that you cannot join twice the table like that, as the ID is not continuous. You're saying `cur.id = pre.id + 1`, but you're not only connecting 1 to 2, 2 to 3, but also 5 to 9 and 9 is more than 5+1. As a solution to this matter, I'd load the simplest version of this table `SELECT * FROM tableA WHERE Name = "A" ORDER BY Date;` and then iterate over it using a `for loop` where there is `cur=i` and `pre=i-1`.

Answer (score 0):

That is very difficult to do in a relational language, but very frequently needed. Therefore welcome to the wonderful world of Oracle's [analytic functions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/Analytic-Functions.html#GUID-527832F7-63C0-4445-8C16-307FA5084056).

```
CREATE TABLE t (id NUMBER, name VARCHAR2(30), amount NUMBER, d DATE);
INSERT INTO t VALUES ( 1,'A', 50, DATE '2018-04-03');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ( 2,'A', 40, DATE '2018-04-03');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ( 3,'A', 30, DATE '2018-04-03');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ( 4,'A', 20, DATE '2018-04-03');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ( 5,'A', 10, DATE '2018-04-08');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ( 6,'B', 20, DATE '2018-04-08');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ( 7,'B', 15, DATE '2018-04-08');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ( 8,'B', 10, DATE '2018-04-08');
INSERT INTO t VALUES ( 9,'A',100, DATE '2018-07-08');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (10,'A', 90, DATE '2018-07-08');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (11,'A', 80, DATE '2018-07-08');
INSERT INTO t VALUES (12,'A', 70, DATE '2018-07-08');
```

The function `LEAD () OVER ()` refers to the next row in the query. In your case, you are only interested in changes for the same value of column `name`, so you specify `PARTITION BY NAME`. For "next" to be meaningful, you'll need to define an order, so you say `ORDER BY id`:

```
SELECT id, name, amount, d,
       LEAD(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY id) AS next_amount,
       LEAD(D)      OVER (PARTITION BY NAME ORDER BY id) AS next_date
  FROM T;
```

This would return your normal values, plus the next amount of the same name:

```
id  name amount d           next_amount  next_date
1   A    50     2018-04-03  40           2018-04-03
2   A    40     2018-04-03  30           2018-04-03
3   A    30     2018-04-03  20           2018-04-03
....
```

But you want only the positive changes, so you'll add a `WHERE` clause. Unfortunately, this works only in a subquery, so it will look like:

```
SELECT id, name, amount, d, next_amount, next_date 
  FROM (
        SELECT id, name, amount, D,
               LEAD(amount) OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) AS next_amount,
               LEAD(D)      OVER (PARTITION BY name ORDER BY id) AS next_date
          FROM t
       ) 
 WHERE amount < next_amount;
```

The result is

```
id  name amount  next_amount  d          next_date
5   A    10      100          2018-04-08 2018-07-08
```